# Unable to attach to application 'iisexpress.exe'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, iis-express

I am trying to run my web application and I get this error

> Unable to attach to application 'iisexpress.exe' (PID 708) using ''.  The version of clr.dll in the target does not match the one mscordacwks.dll was built for.  Do you want to continue anyway?

This was working yesterday.  I have a feeling something has gor corrupted somewhere.

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just had the same problem and I stumbled upon your question. But then I also stumbled upon these:

[The version of clr.dll does not match the one mscordacwks.dll was built for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768138/the-version-of-clr-dll-does-not-match-the-one-mscordacwks-dll-was-built-for)

[The version of clr.dll in the target does not match the one mscordacwks.dll was built for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784310/the-version-of-clr-dll-in-the-target-does-not-match-the-one-mscordacwks-dll-was)

One of 3 things seemed to work for everyone.

1. Restart Visual Studio.
2. If you recently had a windows update but a restart is still pending, then restart your computer.
3. Install Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 from Visual Studio Subscriptions site: https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202010%20service%20pack%201

Comment: For me it was definitely the windows update. After reading this it just came to my attention that I've been postponing that restart :)

Comment: I noticed earlier my CPU spike and that my work forced an update to my machine.  Then I started seeing this error.  Restarting Visual Studio fixed it for me.  Still gonna reboot now cause, why not.

Answer (score 0):

You can open Task manager and end the process named "iisexpress.exe"

Answer (score 0):

Restart you "IIS Express process" if not able to kill process, then Restart your visual studio.[image]