# Unable to attach to application "iisexpress.exe" using "My Computer's Model Number"

Tags: asp.net, windows, visual-studio

This is a strange thing. About last month when I ran this asp.net project on this computer, everything was fine, and yesterday when I used Visual Studio2022 on another computer, I ran this asp.net project and it was still normal, but when I use Visual Studio 2019 in this When debugging this project on a computer, the above words are displayed:

```
Unable to attach to application "iisexpress.exe" using "My Computer's Model Number"
```

Computers that did not work as mentioned above: Windows 7 (has been unchanged)

Computer that worked successfully: Windows 10

This error comes up very unfriendly because I barely changed anything

[Unable to attach to application 'iisexpress.exe'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415258/unable-to-attach-to-application-iisexpress-exe)

This link is hardly helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try the following steps to resolve the issue:

1. Turn off the Windows built-in firewall settings
2. Turn off the anti-virus software running on the computer
3. Disable the automatic startup of antivirus software and restart the computer
4. Run Visual Studio with administrator privileges

Usually, Visual Studio will not have problems for no reason. You may have made some changes in the environment of this computer or downloaded some other software to cause this situation. You can open the task manager to see if there are some suspicious processes running.

Comment: Oddly enough, I did find a process that didn't seem to be expected and had to be closed every time to debug successfully