# The version of clr.dll in the target does not match the one mscordacwks.dll was built for (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to debug a crash dump of a w3wp.exe process in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

When I click to "Debug Managed Only", "Debug Mixed", or "Debug Managed Memory", I get the error:

"Managed debugging is not available for this minidump.  The version of clr.dll in the target does not match the one mscordacwks.dll was built for."

I found a comment on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/20/using-visual-studio-2013-to-diagnose-net-memory-issues-in-production.aspx?PageIndex=2 indicating that the fix is to:

"enable "Microsoft Symbol Servers" in your symbol settings (Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols, check "Microsoft Symbol Servers" and specify a local cache)".

I have done this but I am still getting the error.

I have also tried restarting Visual Studio and rebooting.

I found two related issues in [The version of clr.dll in the target does not match the one mscordacwks.dll was built for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784310/the-version-of-clr-dll-in-the-target-does-not-match-the-one-mscordacwks-dll-was) and [The version of clr.dll does not match the one mscordacwks.dll was built for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768138/the-version-of-clr-dll-does-not-match-the-one-mscordacwks-dll-was-built-for) , but both of these issues deal with Visual Studio 2010 and my problem is with Visual Studio 2013, and the fixes recommended for those issues don't work for me.

Thanks for any tips or ideas....

Comment: There is no simple push-a-button fix for this, the CLR version on your machine *must* match the CLR version on the machine where the minidump was created.  It is a house-keeping job, talk to your IT staff about getting Windows Update enabled on all the machines so you can have some level of assurance that everybody is running the same revision.

Answer (score 2):

A restart of Visual Studio fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the exact scenario I have. Worked on it for about a week and the ONLY way I was able to get this working was using my old dev machine with VS 2012 on the exact same version of the .NET framework that production is running. I was able to see the entire stack trace and I was happy.

I was lead to believe that the symbol servers should load the right versions of everything but it didn't work. Might be a bug in VS 2013. I was tempted to try VS 2015.

I was about try this:
[What to do with “The version of SOS does not match the version of CLR you are debugging” in WinDbg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430769/what-to-do-with-the-version-of-sos-does-not-match-the-version-of-clr-you-are-de/10194213#10194213)
becanse then you can load the version you want. I've never tried WinDbg though.